# Customize bootstrap 5 inputs to be dark

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In my application, I can switch between light and dark modes. I am using Bootstrap 5 form-control inputs, and I would like to change their background color accordingly.

What are the CSS classes I should target to get this to work?

So far I have managed to change the background colors of the inputs, but when the control is active, the color reverts back to white.

```css
.form-control{
    background-color: rgb(45, 52, 61);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was actually very simple. Just never thought of it.

Basically, you should add another CSS rule that targets when the element is in focus.

```css
.form-control {
    background-color: rgb(45, 52, 61);
}

.form-control:focus {
    background-color: rgb(45, 52, 61);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manually overriding Bootstrap CSS you can use the `bg-dark` and `text-white` classes to your inputs. See more about Bootstrap utilities below:

[Bootstrap 5 Utilities - Colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/colors/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="name@example.com">
      <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" id="exampleInputPassword1">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input bg-dark" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This works yes. But what if you want to do this on a global scale so that all inputs change color when theme is switched?

Comment: @PaulBrink haha, classic. Missed the part where doing it on a “global scale” was part of the question. In fact, overriding Bootstrap CSS is just bad practice.

Comment: The issue I have thought is that it doesn't affect the placeholder attribute text. Which it used to in Bootstrap 4.